# muiSlider restrict for certaing range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i'm usign below Mui Slider component
for a UI where i have to restrict it's value for certaing range. For example slider's ball will not dragable after 50. user can select values upto 50 but it will show it full range. i didn't found any direct solution so i figured out a bypass with Discrete Slider Values. here's the code [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/discreteslidervalues-demo-material-ui-forked-gw4rfk?file=/demo.js)  ,Where i have make a array of full available values. Is there any neat and clean solution ?

```
<Slider
  size="small"
  defaultValue={30}
  aria-label="Small"
  valueLabelDisplay="auto"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Fazlay Rabbi it's so simple you need just think out of the box, just need to write simply if condition I write your solution in blow :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Slider from '@mui/material/Slider';

export default function DiscreteSliderLabel() {
  const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(0);
  
  const handleChange2 = (event, newValue) => {
   
    if (newValue > 50){
      setSliderValue(50);
    }else{
      setSliderValue(newValue);
    }
    
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 300 }}>
      <Slider
        value={sliderValue}
        aria-label="Always visible"
        onChange={handleChange2}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks great Solution. But what if you use slider in a table where  we will have multiple sliders?

Comment: Your Wellcome, I need to see your code sample to tell the best solution, we have so many ways to solve it anyway if you get your answer, accept the solution to give me encouragement to continue thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to determine max value for yor slider like below

```
<Slider
   ...
   max={50}
   min={0}
/>
```

And i see your code and i think you can determine marks array for just labels not all values

Comment: not max min. i have to show whats the max value and what can you select. suppose slider max value will be 100, but user can only select upto 50. This is to show that this slider max value is 100 but upto 50 is available for now